# Make second card fill column with Bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

If I have a row with 2 columns how can I make the second card in a column fill the remaining space in the column?

I've tried using `flex-fill` and `flex-grow-1` but does not seem to work.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/dave111223/y6wdh7ob/6/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your two last cards inside a `<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100"></div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/tb0yxn54/

Does it works as you expect ?